# What might these inscriptions added to an «Easy Money» board mean?

Tags: house-rules

These inscriptions, for example **S153** and **P330**, appear to have been added to an **Easy Money** board.

Does anyone know of house rules that might explain their addition?

[image: Board] [image]
(click to enlarge images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The P looks like the payoff value for the mortgage: It's the M value plus 10% (mostly -- it looks like some of the numbers are just approximations to this value or round in arbitrary ways: 175 + 10% is rounded down to 192, while 395 + 10% is rounded up to 435). So: a remedy to having to calculate mortgage payoffs on the fly (and perhaps to avoid arguments over rounding).

The S value is similar: it looks like the B value minus 10%. Perhaps this was a house rule that allowed a player strapped for cash to sell some houses instead of mortgaging the property: selling a house would thus incur a 10% loss.